# What is the concept of "a day" in Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, calendar

We are all practicing westerners time format means a day is starting at midnight 00:00 . What about Hinduism? Does any Hindu scriptures mention about it?

Comment: A day in Hinduism is considered in which sun is shining. Thus it is from sunrise to sunset.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_units_of_time

Answer (score 1):

In Hinduism, in Mahabharata epic, there are many incidents that mentions a day is called from sunrise to sunset.

For any place, where a person can not see sun then it is considered as end of the day. The day starts for that place when a person can see sun from horizons.

In Mahabharata, when Pandava's exile was about to complete, Arjuna appeared in front of Duryodhana, at that time sun was not visible from that place. It was considered as end of the day, hence end of Pandava's exile.

Answer (score 0):

According to ऋग्वेद, the day is divided into 8 pahar(पहर) - 4 pahar for night, 4 for the day. The night pahar starts with the sunset.

> तुर्भि: साकं नवति च नामभिश्चक्रं न वृतं व्यतीखींविपत। बृहच्छरीरो विमिमान ऋक्कभियुर्वाकुमार: प्रत्येत्याहवम॥ (ऋ.म.१.सू.१५५.म.६.)

उक्त मंत्र में गति विशेष द्वारा विविध स्वभाव शाली काल के ९४ अंशों को चक्र की तरह वृत्ताकार कहा गया है। उक्त कालावयवों में १ सम्वतसर २ अयन ५ ऋतुयें १२ माह २४ पक्ष ३० अहोरात्र ८ पहर और १२ आरा मानी गयी हैं।